# civibuild failed to create symbolic link 'bower'

Tags: civicrm-buildkit

i'm trying to configure a dev environment with civicrm buildkit. i have already follow the steps described here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit

but afert use of **`amp config`** and **`amp test`** (with successful results) i'm still getting this error with **`civibuild`**:

```
$ civibuild create civibild-test --type empty
which: no nodejs in (/c/wamp/www/civicrm-buildkit/bin:/c/Users/Administrador/bin:/mingw32/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw32/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/Administrador/bin:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cmd:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/wamp/www/civicrm-buildkit/bin:/c/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12:/c/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/bin:/c/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/bin:/c/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe:/c/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/npm/bin:/c/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin:/c/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin:/c/Users/Administrador/AppData/Roaming/npm:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)
WARNING: pidlockfile.php: POSIX API is unavailable. Cannot lock resources. Concurrent operations may be problematic.
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'bower': File exists
```

In other information i'm using wampserver 2.5 on Windows 7 professional.

Hope you can help me!.